# Enum inheriting from primitive type

Tags: c++, c++11

From questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213743/c-using-primitive-types-as-a-base-class) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143020/why-cant-i-inherit-from-int-in-c), I was under the impression that inheriting from a primitive type would cause a compiler error. However, the following code compiles and produces expected output on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/CB8IO2).

```
#include <iostream>

enum class Test : unsigned short int
{
    TEST, TEST2, TEST3, TEST4
};

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    Test ans = Test::TEST3;

    if(ans == Test::TEST3)
    {
        std::cout << "Here" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Does the fact that the `class` is also an `enum` change the answers in the first two Q&A's? Is this well-defined behavior by the standard?

Comment: The referenced questions are about *classes*, not *enum classes*. Enum classes *can* ‘inherit’ from arithmetic types (I *think* it even defaults to `int`), but *can't* inherit from classes.

Comment: This is an example of the "extend the language by overloading existing syntax to mean something different because we won't add new keywords" strategy.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This does not mean inheritance, this selects the enum's *underlying type*. The underlying type is the integral type which is used to represent the enumerator values.

You can see the difference in this example:

```
#include <iostream>

enum class tiny : bool {
    one, two   
};

enum class bigger : long {
    some, lots   
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << sizeof(tiny::one) << '\n';    //prints 1
    std::cout << sizeof(bigger::some) << '\n'; //prints 8
}
```

In C++11 you can specify the underlying type of both scoped (i.e. `class`) and unscoped enums.

Comment: As an additional comment -- selecting the underlying type is also what allows you to forward declare enum classes, one of the new things that you can't do with C++03 enums. It's definitely supported.

Answer (score 11):

`enum class` was added in C++11 to allow you to specify the underlying type for an enumeration. It reuses the syntax for inheritance as an analogy, but it is not inheritance.

Comment: "*`enum class` was added in C++11 to allow you to specify the underlying type for an enumeration.*" No, it was not; C++11 allowed regular `enum`s` to do that too. The only things `enum class` changes from a regular `enum` are: 1) require scoping of the enumerators by the EC's name. 2) forbid implicit conversions to the underlying class type.

Comment: @NicolBolas - you say "no, it was not", then go on to explain that that's exactly what it does; the fact that there is **another** way to do it doesn't change that.

Comment: Your statement says that `enum class` "was added [...] to allow you...". That implies that this was the sole or at least primary justification for it. When in fact it has nothing to do with `enum class` *specifically*.

Answer (score 6):

It is not inheritance, it is the way to specify underlying type.